# Python- initialisation of built in variables/attributes

Tags: python, initialization, init, built-in, docstring

When and how are the builtin attributes initialized?
`__doc__`, `__name__` (I guess I know about this one :) ), `__class__`, `__setattr__` etc.

In my other question regarding docstrings, one of the answers mentioned that docstrings are just simple strings and I tried with `'`, `"` and `"""` and they all worked. But when I used a variable assigned the string value and put that variable in place of the docstring, it doesn't work. That's why I started wondering when does the `__doc__` attribute get initialized?

EDIT:
This is what I have tried on interpreter (yes, this is crazy and I am wierd :D)

```
doc_str = "Says Hello world"


class HelloWorld():
    def say():
        doc_str
        print("Hello world !")

h_w = HelloWorld()
h_w.say.__doc__


class AnotherHelloWorld():

    def __init__(self, doc_str="Says HELLO WORLD"):
        self.doc_str = doc_str

    def say(self):
        self.doc_str
        print("HELLO WORLD !")

a_h_w = AnotherHelloWorld("Scream... HELLO WORLD!")
a_h_w.say.__doc__


class YetAnotherHelloWorld():

    def __init__(self, doc_str="Still does't say HELLO WORLD :( "):
        self.doc_str = doc_str

    def say(self):
          "%s"%self.doc_str
          print("HELLO WORLD .. Again!")
```

Comment: "But when I used a variable assigned the string value and put that variable in place of the docstring, it doesn't work." Show us.

Comment: @Sean, I just clicked the edit link, before which the text required the editing, but the page loaded with editing done :) nice timing !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's different for each one. (After all, each one's [special](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#specialnames)!) Some are the class attributes, some are instance attributes, some are inherited.

`__doc__` is initialized when the class is created (you can also pass it in the `dict` argument to the `type` constructor). The special syntax only works for string literals, but if you need a variable docstring you can set it explicitly:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    __doc__ = "This is class #{0}.".format(1)
```

`__name__` is also set when the class is created.

`__class__` is set when an instance is created (i.e. in `__new__`).

`__setattr__` and friends are inherited from `object`.

Comment: Thanks :) I am learnig something which i didnt learn in books(or it was __me__ who missed it?)